# place smaller array in large array while ignoring zeros

Tags: python, numpy

i have a large array and want to place a smaller array at some offset and at the same time ignore zeros in the smaller array. what's the best way to do that?

I tried masked arrays but somehow this is slow

```
mask = np.ma.masked_equal(pixels, 0, False)
output[offset_y:offset_y+tile_height,offset_x:offset_x+tile_width] = np.where(mask.mask, output[offset_y:offset_y+tile_height,offset_x:offset_x+tile_width], pixels)
```

then i tried this

```
np.place(output[offset_y:offset_y+tile_height,offset_x:offset_x+tile_width], pixels>0, pixels[pixels>0])
```

but it is very slow

what is the fastest way to do so?

Comment: Create a new empty array of the right size, and copy values to it from both the original and new arrays.  I'd try to remove the zeros from the smaller array first.

Comment: Give us some idea of the size and shape of the arrays you are dealing with.  Better yet, give us some small small arrays to test.

Comment: the size of output is 30000x50000 and the pixels are 16000x16000..

Comment: i think it should be fast with masked arrays but i am not sure why it does not work

Comment: just updated the masked array example to a working one

Comment: It sounds like you might want to use sparse matrices for this - are most of the values in `output` also zeros?

Comment: at the beginning output is all zeros but the pixels are not and then later output is not zeros

Answer (score 2):

I suspect regular old logical indexing will be the most efficient here:

```
# make a view into output with the same dimensions as `pixels`
output_subarray = output[offset_y:offset_y+tile_height,offset_x:offset_x+tile_width]

mask = pixels != 0
output_subarray[mask] = pixels[mask]
```